# Why does my world seem to be getting smaller?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My buildings are all disappearing - almost like my world has gotten smaller. I’m on Minecraft PE, and my world is on the old settings. I know that it’s not deleted because I can still see signs, beds and chests in the missing chunk, and animals can still enter the area, but if I go into it I can never get out and it just looks as if I had flown up in the air high enough were it’s just sky and clouds.
How can I fix this issue and what is it caused by?

[image][image][image][image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on what happens when you go over to these missing areas? I remember on PC that when this happened, it was just "loading chunks", and after a little time (a few seconds, depending on computer speed), the "chunk" would appear.

Comment: It wouldn’t I have tried reloading it and turning off my phone and turning it back on nothing is working

Comment: maybe you are just getting bigger

Comment: Not sure about PE, but in JE this just means the chunk didn't load properly. If you far enough away and come back, or save and quit and load the world again, it will hopefully world the second time. Usually the chunk is just fine (not corrupted), just not displayed on the screen for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

These are probably in the same shape as the "chunks" in your world, and typically form when a chunk has been loaded incorrectly or corrupted. As animals can still enter it it's probably just an error loading your world.

Restarting your world should work (as in either restarting the server it's hosted on, or restarting your game). If you're playing with your cousins see if they can see the issue too. If all of you can not go into the areas it may be that that chunk is corrupted and you may have to restore a backup (if you have one).

Comment: My cousins see it too and I have tried restarting everything and it doesn’t work

Comment: Then as I said it is most likely a world corruption - something that won't be fixable. In future make sure that your device storage isn't near full to prevent this happening again, and don't corrupt your worlds by closing the app while a save is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. If you create a copy, then make it infinite, it will load the chunks. Unfortunately, you no longer have an old world.

Comment: Would this remove all of the stuff built in the old world, or?

Comment: No, it would just add new chunks

Answer (score 0):

Well this has happened before to me and a couple of my fave YouTubers idk why but because this is an old world it just seems to corrupt the world for some reason. Basically your builds haven’t been deleted they have just strangely turned invisible, so the AI mobs still think it is there. Strangely signs and things show up but all this is, is some sort of weird world corruption glitch.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Try to update your minecraft or reset your nether that should help

Comment: There is no update yet I’ve checked